# Validation error FAST API -response model

Tags: python, backend, fastapi, pydantic

```
@router.get("/",status_code=status.HTTP_200_OK,response_model= schemas.postout)
def get_posts(db: session= Depends(get_db),current_user : int= Depends(oath2.get_current_user)):
        cursor.execute("select * from posts")
        posts=cursor.fetchall()
        returned_post= db.query(models.Post).all()
    
    return {'data': returned_post}
```

This gives me the error an error. However, if I remove the response model, I get a dictionary response as expected. Not making sense to me. The schemas I want to use for the response is postout below:

```
class post(BaseModel):
    title: str
    content: str
    published: bool=True
    
    class Config:
    orm_mode= True
    
class postout(post):
    id: int
    created_at: datetime
    creator_id: int
    class Config:
        orm_mode= True
```

The error I get is :

> pydantic.error_wrappers.ValidationError: 5 validation errors for postout

```
response -> title
  field required (type=value_error.missing)
response -> content
  field required (type=value_error.missing)
response -> id
  field required (type=value_error.missing)
response -> created_at
  field required (type=value_error.missing)
response -> creator_id
  field required (type=value_error.missing)
```

If I removed the response model (`response_model= schemas.postout`) in the API I get the output response I should get :

```
"data": [
        {
            "published": true,
            "id": 8,
            "creator_id": 12,
            "title": "whatever I want2",
            "content": "Some cool stuff I wanted",
            "created_at": "2022-12-28T16:03:01.391997+00:00"
        },
        {
            "published": true,
            "id": 14,
            "creator_id": 12,
            "title": "whatever I want2",
            "content": "Some cool stuff I wanted",
            "created_at": "2022-12-28T16:22:43.757510+00:00"
```

Answer (score 1):

About this decorator:

```
@router.get("/",status_code=status.HTTP_200_OK, response_model= schemas.postout)
```

the [docs](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/response-model/) for `response_model` say that:

> FastAPI will use this response_model to:
>
> - Convert the output data to its type declaration.
> - Validate the data.
> - Add a JSON Schema for the response, in the OpenAPI path operation.
> - Will be used by the automatic documentation systems.
>
> But most importantly:
>
> - Will limit the output data to that of the model.

which means a `postout` instance is expected from `get_posts()`, instead of this:

```
returned_post= db.query(models.Post).all()
return {'data': returned_post}
```

thus pydantic is telling that all fields for `postout` validation is failing, included the ones inherited from `post` (i.e. `title`).

Comment: i follow, so how do I fix it. Post out(returned_post)??  I'm following a tutorial and the code worked fine for the instructor, and mine is identical.

Comment: You're getting a JSON {"data": ... } made from a collection of `postout`s, not a single `postout`. The `postout`s are nested into "data". Anyway, I'll leave this to better FastAPI experts than me.

Comment: got it. Response model has to be entered as a List. That's why it wasn't working  -.-''

Answer (score 1):

response model has to be entered as a list.....-.-'' so this :

```
@router.get("/",status_code=status.HTTP_200_OK,
response_model=List[schemas.postout] )
```